# Can not find wifi adaptor in wintel8 Cherry Trail CR Atom z8350 Ubunto

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, intel

I brought home the minipc mentioned above and the first thing I did was installing ubunto v20.04. However, I am having trouble getting the wifi to connect. The bluethooth meanwhile seems to be working fine.

I have tried to update the drives using an Ethernet connection but with no luck. The problem seems to be that the OS does not recognize the wireless adaptor

Here is the output of `lspci -knn`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register [8086:2280] (rev 36)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register [8086:7270]
        Kernel driver in use: iosf_mbi_pci
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:22b0] (rev 36)
        DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:7270]
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
    00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller [8086:22b5] (rev 36)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller [8086:7270]
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
        Kernel modules: xhci_pci
    00:1a.0 Encryption controller [1080]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine [8086:2298] (rev 36)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine [8086:7270]
        Kernel driver in use: mei_txe
        Kernel modules: mei_txe
    00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 [8086:22c8] (rev 36)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU [8086:229c] (rev 36)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU [8086:7270]
        Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
        Kernel modules: lpc_ich
    01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
        Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:0123]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
```

And the lsub output

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0620 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.2 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0d8c:0014 C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A)
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 093a:1688 Pixart Imaging, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1ea7:2010 SHARKOON Technologies GmbH USB2.1 Hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1a40:0201 Terminus Technology Inc. FE 2.1 7-port Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:c820 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

edit Here is the minipc [model](https://www.amazon.in/Wintel-CherryTrail-1-84GHz-Computer-Bluetooth/dp/B06VWF14YC) I have

Finally the `sudo lshw -c network` output

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 07
       serial: 68:1d:ef:20:a1:5c
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-55-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.1.76 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:91404000-91404fff memory:91400000-91403fff
```

Any help is appreciated

`

Comment: What you've provided us is the specs for the processor on the system - this is NOT the model of computer you have.  Based on the `lspci` output I would say that your system does NOT have a wifi card in it, however without the specific model system you're using or working with, nobody will be able to ID if it came with a card or not.  Check `lsusb` as well in case its' a wifi adapter on an internal USB connection - that won't show in lspci if it is

Comment: May we also see: `lsusb` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep -i sdio` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: And `sudo lshw -c network`.

Comment: I have edited the post above with the model and the command outputs. `sudo dmesg | grep -i sdio` did not produce an output